# How do I parametrize this chapterimage command by an opacity argument?

Tags: macros, arguments, parameters, renewcommand

I have the following *chapterimage* command, based on [this book template (ILM Report by Jenny Lantair)](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ilm-report/ycszftwbvmhp) which I use simply by this oneliner: `\chapterimage{./res/headers/nature.jpg}`.

```
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}}

\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{
\thispagestyle{empty}
{\centering
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\startcontents
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}};
\draw[anchor=west] (16cm,-25px) node [fill=white!10!white,text opacity=1,draw=white,draw opacity=1,line width=1pt,fill opacity=.6,inner sep=12pt]{\huge\bfseries\textcolor{black}{#1\strut\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\par\vspace*{180\p@}
\fi
\fi}
```

It works well and when I use for example:

```
\chapterimage{./res/headers/nature.jpg}
\chapter{Intakte Natur}
```

it outputs:

[image]

***My question:*** Currently the opacity of the white box behind the chapter title is set to **0.6** and when I set it to for example **0.8** it will be applied globally. How can I extend it by an opacity argument, i.e.: `\chapterimage[0.8]{./res/headers/nature.jpg}`? I would like to be able to set the opacity for some (not all) chapters to an individual value (other than **0.6**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this does the trick:

```latex
\newcommand\MyExchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand{\MyOpacity}{}
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[2][0.6]{%
  \edef\MyOpacity{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \edef\thechapterimage{\unexpanded{#2}}%
}

\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
{\centering
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\startcontents
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}};
\expandafter\MyExchange
\expandafter{\MyOpacity}{%
  \draw[anchor=west] (16cm,-25px) node [fill=white!10!white,text opacity=1,draw=white,draw opacity=1,line width=1pt,fill opacity=%
},inner sep=12pt]{\huge\bfseries\textcolor{black}{#1\strut\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\par\vspace*{180\p@}%
\fi
\fi}
```

...

```latex
\chapterimage[0.8]{./res/headers/nature.jpg}
\chapter{Intakte Natur}
```

In case you wish to change values of keys other than the "fill opacity"-key as well:

```latex
\newcommand\MyExchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand{\MyMoreKeyVals}{}
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[2][]{%
  \edef\MyMoreKeyVals{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \edef\thechapterimage{\unexpanded{#2}}%
}

\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\thispagestyle{empty}%
{\centering
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\startcontents
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.north west)
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}};
\expandafter\MyExchange
\expandafter{\MyMoreKeyVals}{%
  \draw[anchor=west] (16cm,-25px) node [fill=white!10!white,text opacity=1,draw=white,draw opacity=1,line width=1pt,fill opacity=.6,inner sep=12pt,%
}]{\huge\bfseries\textcolor{black}{#1\strut\makebox[22cm]{}}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\par\vspace*{180\p@}%
\fi
\fi}
```

...

```latex
\chapterimage[fill opacity=0.8]{./res/headers/nature.jpg}
\chapter{Intakte Natur}
```

---

This is untested because you did not provide enough code/context for testing.

Comment: It works great! Thank you for your answer. You may test it and see it working using [Jenny Lantair's Overleaf Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ilm-report/ycszftwbvmhp).